# Beaglebone dcan0 and dcan1

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, beagleboneblack

I have a linux image created with yocto for beaglebone black. I need to configure dcan0 and dcan1, as well as bunch of gpios and few uarts. For this, i've created a bunch of .dtsi files and included them in a custom .dts and created patches to include all the changes. Everything works fine, exept for dcan0 and dcan1 (i've removed i2c2) checked with:

```
cat /sys/kernel/debug/pinctrl/44e10800.pinmux-pinctrl-single/pinmux-pins
```

This is my dcan0 configuration, dcan1 looks pretty much the same, just different pins are used :

```
&am33xx_pinmux {
    dcan0_pins_default: dcan0_pins_default {
        pinctrl-single,pins = <
            AM33XX_IOPAD(0x97c, PIN_INPUT | MUX_MODE2) /* (D17) uart1_rtsn.dcan0_rx */
            AM33XX_IOPAD(0x978, PIN_OUTPUT | MUX_MODE2) /* (D18) uart1_ctsn.dcan0_tx */
        >;
    };
};

&dcan0 {
    status = "okay";
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl1-0 = <&dcan0_pins_default>;
};
```

After this i've added configuration of dcan0 and dca1 to am33xx.dtsi as follows:

```
+   d_can@481cc000 {
+            compatible = "bosch,d_can";
+            ti,hwmods = "d_can0";
+            reg = <0x481cc000 0x2000>;
+            interrupts = <0x34>;
+            status = "disabled";
+            linux,phandle = <0x2c>;
+            phandle = <0x2c>;
+        };
+ 
+        d_can@481d0000 {
+            compatible = "bosch,d_can";
+            ti,hwmods = "d_can1";
+            reg = <0x481d0000 0x2000>;
+            interrupts = <0x37>;
+            status = "disabled";
+            linux,phandle = <0x2d>;
+            phandle = <0x2d>;
+        };
```

Once again, cans are not present. Does anyone have idea why isn't it working? I have my uarts configured the same way and they are all working.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to overload properties within `&dcan0` which is using the `phandle` method. You can do this only if you have specified a label for the device described in the Device Tree.
In am33xx.dtsi:

```
/ {
    can@f09237 {
        some-properties;
    };
};
```

To overload or add properties to the above device, you need to do in your other DTS(I) which is including the DTSI, the following:
In mycustom.dts:

```
/ {
    can@f09237 {
        some-other-properties;
    };
};
```

You need to respect the exact path from `/`. So if you have the following:
In am33xx.dtsi:

```
/ {
    bus@9908ab {
        can@f09237 {
            some-properties;
        };
    };
};
```

In mycustom.dtsi, you should have:

```
/ {
    bus@9908ab {
        can@f09237 {
            some-other-properties;
        };
    };
};
```

The second way to overload/add properties to a device is to make use of `phandle`s. For that you need a label:
In am33xx.dtsi:

```
/ {
    can0: can@f09237 {
        some-properties;
    };
};
```

In mycustom.dts:

```
// Technically not needed but just to show it should be outside of this, the root of the DTS
/ {
};

&can0 {
    some-other-properties;
};
```

If there isn't a label for your node but one for the parent node such as in the following example:
In am33xx.dtsi:

```
/ {
    bus0: bus@9908ab {
        can@f09237 {
            some-properties;
        };
    };
};
```

In mycustom.dtsi, you can do the following (which is basically a mix of phandle and path methods):

```
&bus0 {
    can@f09237 {
        some-other-properties;
    };
};
```

I'd go with the phandle method personally, it's way more readable and easier to find where the original node was defined.

IIRC (not 100% sure about that one), you don't have to add the phandle in am33xx.dtsi, you can add it elsewhere, but you obviously need to respect one of the solutions above to overload the Device Tree node.
E.g., with the first example for am33xx.dtsi, you can have in mycustom.dts (or separate the label declaration in an intermediary mycustom.dtsi):

```
/ {
    can0: can@f09237 {
    };
};

&can0 {
    some-other-properties;
};
```

Otherwise, I'm pretty surprised to see `linux,phandle` and `phandle` in your Device Tree, that is pretty ancient and not used anymore in DTS (though, it actually is put there by DTC when compiling your DTS). Also, I doubt `linux,phandle` is deterministic, it is usually created on the fly by DTC, by just incrementing a number each time a `phandle` is created.

Comment: So basicly i should remove linux,phandle = <0x2d>;  phandle = <0x2d>; yes ?

Comment: I think they are useless in your case. What you need to do is use the correct way to overload DeviceTree nodes. You're mixing two ways. Either you add a label to your node in am33xx.dtsi or you overload it by path. One of the two ways explained above. Let me add the name of the files where the code snippets have to be written.